# Calling a static void Java method from JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

My C code does not manage to find the public static function call I have in Java. It manages to find the class without error.

I am attempting to return a result to a callback method `onResponse`. "5" will be replaced by something more complex later.

I have seem similar questions on StackOverflow, but no changes so far seem to have helped. Perhaps I have a logic error?

**My JNI (updated #2):**

```
void cec_debug_msg(JNIEnv *env, cec_rx_message_t* msg) {
    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/utils/CECUtils");
    if(!cls) {
        LOGE("Could not find the CEC class.");
    } else {
        jmethodID methodid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "onResponse", "(I)V");
        if(!methodid) {
            // Code always reaches this point, never finding the method
            LOGE("Could not find the callback method.");
        } else {
            LOGV("Called static void method.");
            (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cls, methodid, 5);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is contained in a method that is called from this function:

```
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_example_utils_CECUtils_startListening(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls) {

    ...

    cec_debug_msg(env, &rx_msg);

    ...

}
```

**My Java (updated #1):**

```
public class CECUtils {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("cecutils");
    }

    public static native int startListening();

    ...

    public static void onResponse(int opcode) {
        Utils.log("CEC", "From JNI!");
    }

}
```

**Signature check:**

> javap -s -p CECUtils
>
> public static void onResponse(int);
>
> Signature: (I)V

### Solution: Check ProGuard!

```
-keep public class com.example.utils.CECUtils {
    *;
}
```

Comment: ProGuard was the problem for me. Code was working fine in debug, but the release version was mashing the java class and JNI could no longer find the methods. Adding my error here to help future searches: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/domain/path/to/MyClass;.javaFuncCalledFromJNI(Ljava/lang/String;)V"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `GetStaticMethodID` instead of `GetMethodID`.

Note, you will need to call `CallStaticVoidMethod` instead of `CallVoidMethod` also.

See here for more info: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I have the same problem. I'll look at your link.

Comment: I added code that better reflects my actual code. Just to be more complete.

Comment: The error was simply ProGuard. I didn't add an exception. Setting your comment as answer, because you caught my initial error.

Answer (score 5):

see the **method signatures**  (http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html)

jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "callback", **"(I)V"**); the (I)V determines the signature

Here is the docs of GetMethodID:

> **GetMethodID**
>
> jmethodID GetMethodID(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, const char *name,
>   **const char *sig**);
>
> Returns the method ID for an instance (nonstatic) method of a class or
>   interface. The method may be defined in one of the clazz’s
>   superclasses and inherited by clazz. The method is determined by its
>   name and signature.
>
> GetMethodID() causes an uninitialized class to be initialized.
>
> To obtain the method ID of a constructor, supply  as the method
>   name and void (V) as the return type.

maybe you can use **javap** to determine the signature of your method:

> **Using javap to Generate Method Signatures**
>
> To eliminate the mistakes in deriving method signatures by hand, you
>   can use the javap tool to print out method signatures. For example, by
>   running:
>
> ```
> javap -s -p Prompt
> ```
>
> you can obtain the following output:
>
> ```
> Compiled from Prompt.java
> class Prompt extends java.lang.Object 
>     /* ACC_SUPER bit set */
> {
>     private native getLine (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
>     public static main ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
>     <init> ()V
>     static <clinit> ()V
> }
> ```

The "-s" flag informs javap to output signatures rather than normal Java types. The "-p" flag causes private members to be included.

Comment: The signature matches:

  `public static void onResponse(int);
    Signature: (I)V`

Comment: is the method onResponse a class method of CECUtils ?

Comment: oh, this is obsolete, it is a class method. i have no ideas anymore. i do not know from which device you get the value that is written in &rx_msg but maybe you should check such elementar things like firewalls etc i.e. the ufw in linux drops UDP packets

Comment: rx_msg can be ignored really. The main thing is getting the onResponse method detected.

Comment: The error was simply ProGuard. I didn't add an exception.

Comment: in its declaration onResponse(int opcode) is given the variable int opcode when looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306710/getobjectclass-method-and-findclass-method-difference-and-usage the JNI has to allocate the fields and therefore also the field for int opcode that is in the java environment ??? maybe the JNI can not allocate the field int opcode in the java memory space because it was not declared to the JNI ?

Comment: these are the meanest ones ! it also took me an hour to figure out that the ufw drops my udp packets (IEEE 802.15.4 device)